# Почему не выводятся картинки в Django?

Tags: python, django

Тут такая проблема: картинка, загруженная через админку, не выводится на главную страницу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код views.py (как по мне, именно здесь и проблема):

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'Homepage/index.html'
model = Goods
context_object_name = 'goods'

def description(self):
    return self.description_text

def price(self):
    return self.price_text

def image(self):
    return self.image_sale
```

вот код от models.py:

```
class Goods(models.Model):
description_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
price_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
image_sale = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='media/')

def __str__(self):
    return self.image_sale


def __str__(self):
    return self.description_text

def __str__(self):
    return self.price_text
```

вот путь картинок в settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

вот как выглядит шаблон index.html

```html
{% if good.image %}
        <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ good.image_sale }}">
{% endif %}
```

вот как выглядит построение media:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Самое нужное — шаблон — не показали

Comment: @andreymal хорошо, добавил, теперь можете помочь ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему не показываются картинки в Django?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1346319/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-django)