# Почему не показываются картинки в Django?

Tags: python, django

Тут такая проблема: картинка, загруженная через админку, не выводится на главную страницу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код views.py (как по мне, именно здесь и проблема):

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'Homepage/index.html'
model = Goods
context_object_name = 'goods'

def description(self):
    return self.description_text

def price(self):
    return self.price_text

def image(self):
    return self.image_sale
```

вот код от models.py:

```
class Goods(models.Model):
description_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
price_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
image_sale = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='media/')

def __str__(self):
    return self.image_sale


def __str__(self):
    return self.description_text

def __str__(self):
    return self.price_text
```

вот путь картинок в settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

вот как выглядит шаблон index.html

```html
{% if good.image %}
        <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ good.image_sale }}">
{% endif %}
```

вот как выглядит построение media:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Папка `/media/` это самостоятельная директория, вынеси её из `/static/` или придется переписать все пути, но это такое...

Comment: а ничего что у вас media внутри static, а в настройках выпишете что в корне?

Comment: @em0ji хорошо я вынес, что дальше ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дальше проверяешь все настройки...

`setting.py`:

```
import os

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        ...
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'))]
```

`urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('image.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

`models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Goods(models.Model):
    description_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image_sale = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description_text

    def __str__(self):
        return self.price_text
```

`views.py`:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Goods

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Goods
    template_name = 'index.html'
```

`urls.py` приложения:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Картинка</title>
</head>
    <body>
        {% for goods in goods_list %}
            <img src="{{ goods.image_sale.url }}" alt="">
        {% endfor %}
    </body> 
</html>
```

А вот как выглядит структура приложения `image` [image: screen] У меня все загруженные картинки через админку отображаются на странице. Галочку не забудь прожать)

`requirements.txt`:

```
asgiref==3.4.1
Django==3.2.9
Pillow==8.4.0
pytz==2021.3
sqlparse==0.4.2
```

Добавлю ниже кусочек кода который отработал у автора вопроса:

```
<body>
    {% for good in goods %}
        <img src="{{ good.image_sale.url }}" alt="">
    {% endfor %}
</body>
```

Comment: то есть мне нужно создать ещё одно приложение я правильно понимаю ?

Comment: Нет не правильно, тебе надо добавить или отредактировать код у себя и всё заработает

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'image', где-то я облажался

Comment: добавь в проект Pillow `pip install pillow` и перепроверь код

Comment: Ошибка `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'image'` вытекает из `path('', include('image.urls')),` проверь файл `urls.py` и сделай необходимые правки.

Comment: У меня всё установленно точь вточь, те же версии но проблема не в них

Comment: проблема в том, что ты в глобальном `urls.py` использовал мой модуль `image`...  а потом пишешь про ошибки, конечно они у тебя будут

Comment: Проблему решил только в вашем ответе подправьте `{% for goods in goods_list %}
            <img src="{{ goods.image_sale.url }}" alt="">
        {% endfor %}` на `{% for good in goods %}
    <img src="{{good.image_sale.url }}">
    {% endfor %}` а так вам огромное спасибо, и галочку вы заработали)

Comment: при таких изменениях вывод картинок перестает работать у меня, поэтому просто ниже дописал, то что сработало у тебя.

Comment: так посмотри код от вьюшки у меня там имя объекта не goods_list а goods `context_object_name = 'goods'` или это вообще не имеет значения ?

Comment: вообще разница есть, но комменты не место чтобы разводить полемику. Это политика stackoverflow. Хотя на последок, я дам тебе совет, в следующий раз называй модели не во множественном числе, а в единственном. Вроде это как негласное правило. Если ничего не делать, то в админке у тебя будет Goodss множественное число))