# Django. Загрузка изображений

Tags: python, django, изображения, pillow

Помогите освоить тему загрузки изображений в Django(Python).

1. Если есть рекомендации, то прошу дать ссылку на книгу.
2. Показать пример(самый легкий), как загрузить изображение при создании WEB.

p.s. Изучаю самостоятельно. Перепробовал несколько вариантов. Выскакивают ошибки. Описывать детально и где не вижу смысла. (уже сам запутался). Лучше если это будет книга.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Можешь вот тут посмотреть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1346319/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-django/1346696#1346696